# How to get and use the latest context value in context's function using React functional component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, state, react-context

I have this small React application. I am using the power of context.

On clicking on the list item, I want to update the context value's state and call one of the context functions with the latest value. But I always get stale(previous value).

***app-context.js***

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';

export const AppContext = React.createContext({
    pageIndex: 0,
    setPageIndex: () => { },
    getVideos: async () => {}
});

export const AppContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [pageIndex, setPageIndex] = useState(0);

  async function getVideos() {
    console.log(pageIndex); // always get stale value.
    // TODO:- call the await fetch API to get videos but with latest index.
  }
  const context = {
    pageIndex,
    getVideos,
    setPageIndex
  }
  return <AppContext.Provider value={context}>{children}</AppContext.Provider>
}
```

***App.js***

```js
import React, { useState, useContext, useEffect } from 'react';
import { AppContext } from './app-context'

const App = () => {
    const { pageIndex, getVideos, setPageIndex } = useContext(AppContext)
    const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(1);

    const paginate = async (i) => {
        setCurrentPage(i)
        setPageIndex(currentPage)
        getVideos()
    }
    
    return (
        <div>
            <p>Current Page:- {currentPage}</p>
            <ul>
                <li onClick={() => paginate(1)}>1</li>
                <li onClick={() => paginate(2)}>2</li>
                <li onClick={() => paginate(3)}>3</li>
                <li onClick={() => paginate(4)}>4</li>
                <li onClick={() => paginate(5)}>5</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    )
}

export default App;
```

Comment: `pageIndex` only updates once your app rerenders. Consider passing `i` into `getVideos()` as well and using that instead?

Comment: That's what I was thinking, need to update the definition of getVideos fn. But I was looking for the best solution, I mean how the react dev solves such cases instead of passing as an argument.

Comment: @SachinKumar the setters for modifying state are asynchronous so you won't see the updated value right after setting. Don't over think this or try to be clever. Just pass `i` as Nick Parsons suggests.

Comment: Alright, I think this is only the way. I guess I can't use the callback of setState in the functional component[or hooks].

Comment: @SachinKumar Yeah, you _could_ do stuff with `useEffect()` that calls `getVideos()` when `pageIndex` changes, but that's not really the purpose of `useEffect()`, and most likely not what you want to do here (the [react docs](https://react.dev/learn/you-might-not-need-an-effect#sharing-logic-between-event-handlers) also don't recommend this approach either)